# ulimit -u gives illegal option error when running from a script but not when from a terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, ulimit

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "OUTPUT:"
gcc temp.c
echo "ACTOP"
ulimit -t 1
ulimit -f 1024
ulimit -u 3
./a.out > out.txt
```

The output I get is

```
OUTPUT: 
ACTOP 
ulimit: 7: Illegal option -u
```

But if I use `ulimit -u 3` in the terminal directly it works. The `-t` and `-f` options work fine  however.

When I change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` it works, but now it refuses to execute code unless the no. of allowed processes > 132.
Anything less than ulimit -u 132 does not allow execution.
In the terminal directly I was able to work with `ulimit -u 3`.

Comment: What does your `temp.c` code do?

Answer (score 4):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin, not a program:

```
$ type ulimit
ulimit is a shell builtin
```

What it means is that `ulimit` may not work the same way with every shell.

The default shell in Ubuntu is Bash, and it is the shell you use from the terminal.

However in your script you are using `sh`, which (by default) is provided by is Dash, a shell similar, but different from Bash. Compare:

```
$ bash
$ ulimit -u
29901
$ dash
$ ulimit -u
dash: 1: ulimit: Illegal option -u
```

There are at least two solutions for your problem:

1. change your shebang from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`;
2. use `-p` instead of `-u`.

I would recommend the first solution, because Bash has many more features than Dash. The drawback is that Bash is slower, but it your script is not performance-critical, this won't be a problem.

For more information about the difference between Bash's `ulimit` and Dash's `ulimit`, you can see `man bash` and `man dash`, then perform a search typing `/ulimit`. Additionally, Bash provides a `help` builtin that you can use as an alternative to the man page.